# posting stream data to WCF with Apache HTTP client

Tags: android, json, wcf, httpclient

I am trying to post a json string to my wcf service. The issue is that my WCF method expects a Stream object and not just a JSON.

Here is the method header in WCF:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "person/delete", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Person DeletePerson(Stream streamdata)
```

Here is what I have been trying:

```
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + uri);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
    InputStreamEntity ise = new InputStreamEntity(is, data.getBytes().length);
    ise.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ise.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
    request.setEntity(ise);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get 400 bad request with this and everything else ive tried. Could someone please help me get this working!? Also, it has to be done with HttpClient because I have custom authentication code working with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + uri);
    AbstractHttpEntity entity = new AbstractHttpEntity() {
        public boolean isRepeatable() { return true; }
        public long getContentLength() { return -1; }
        public boolean isStreaming() { return false; }
        public InputStream getContent() throws IOException { throw new     UnsupportedOperationException(); }
        public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8");
            writer.write(arr, 0, arr.length);
            writer.flush();
        }
    };

    entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    InputStream bais = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity he = response.getEntity();
        bais = he.getContent();
        result = convertStreamToString(bais);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```